# Tailwind: make two sibling divs same height responsively

Tags: tailwind-css

I want to put an image next to a text, but I want the image and the text to be the same height.

I have found a lot of ways this is suppoused to be done, but none has worked.

As can be seen in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/60shvm8d/2/

I want that in bigger displays the image to be cropped with `object-fit: cover` and to have the same height as the text, but in smaller displays, i want the div on the right to be as tall as the image and to have an scroll.

How can I achieve that?

If that can't be done, I want at least that the height of the div with the image to be limited by the one with the text, even in bigger displays.

Answer (score 1):

It's easier if you know what you need. For example "table-cell" would be the answer on your question.

Here is the Link: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display

```
<div class="table w-full">
  <div class="table-row-group">
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">A cell with more content <br></div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 2</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row">
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 4</div>
      <div class="table-cell">A cell with more content</div>
      <div class="table-cell">Cell 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```